# Dimensional reduction of supermultiplets

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, supersymmetry, supergravity

Consider the (10d) IIA supergravity multiplet: (in terms of $SO(8)$ representations) a graviton $\boldsymbol{44}$, a 1-form $\boldsymbol{8}_V$, a 2-form $\boldsymbol{28}$, a 3-form $\boldsymbol{56}_V$, 2 gravitini $\boldsymbol{56}_S$, $\boldsymbol{56}_C$, 2 dilatinos $\boldsymbol{8}_S$, $\boldsymbol{8}_C$, and 1 scalar $\boldsymbol{1}$.

I want to reduce to 6 dimensions. I find the following fields (i.e. $SO(4)\sim SU(2)\times SU(2)$ representations, labelled as usual as $(2j+1,2j'+1)$): 1 graviton $(\boldsymbol{3,3})$, 25 scalars $(\boldsymbol{1,1})$, 16 1-forms $(\boldsymbol{2,2})$, 10 2-forms $(\boldsymbol{3,1})$ and $(\boldsymbol{1,3})$, 8 gravitinos $(\boldsymbol{2,3})$ and $(\boldsymbol{3,2})$, and 40 fermions $(\boldsymbol{2,1})$ and $(\boldsymbol{1,2})$.

On the standard reference "Extended Poincaré Supersymmetry" by Strathdee, specifically in Table 1, this is given as the $\mathcal{N}=(4,4)$ supergravity multiplet in 6d. This is my first point of confusion -- the 10d IIA theory has $\mathcal{N}=(1,1)$, i.e. 32 supercharges (given that the minimal spinor in 10d has 16 components). But 32 supercharges in 6d (where the minimal spinor has 8 components) would correspond to $\mathcal{N}=(2,2)$, wouldn't it? Why do I seem to get the $\mathcal{N}=(4,4)$ supermultiplet instead? Or am I reading Strathdee wrong?

Secondly, Strathdee writes down the 6d supermultiplets in terms of $SO(4)\times USp(2)\times USp(2)$ (for the $\mathcal{N}=(2,2)$ case) or $SO(4)\times USp(4)\times USp(4)$ (for the $\mathcal{N}=(4,4)$ case) representations. How would I be able to do this? For example, if on Mathematica I decompose the 10d graviton $\boldsymbol{44}$ into $SO(4)\times USp(2)\times USp(2)$, where I write $SO(4)$ as $SU(2)\times SU(2)$, I find $$(\boldsymbol{1,1,1,1})\oplus(\boldsymbol{2,2,2,2})\oplus(\boldsymbol{3,3,1,1})\oplus(\boldsymbol{1,1,3,3})$$
but for instance, the $(\boldsymbol{1,1,3,3})$ factor does not figure either in the $\mathcal{N}=(2,2)$ nor in the $\mathcal{N}=(4,4)$ multiplets given by Strathdee.